# Enable X-XSS-Protection in an ASP.Net MVC Web app

Tags: xss, asp.net

Most of the browsers supports the X-XSS-Protection header to prevent XSS atatcks. How we can enable this header in a ASP.Net MVC application?

Do we need to enable it in the application or do we need to do some configuration in the IIS?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635403/how-to-set-http-header-x-xss-protection (Answers explicitly refer to ASP.Net.)

Comment: Just don't rely on that header as your only protection in XSS - it is not perfect in all situations. But it can still be good in some situations. Also, in IE8 (and possibly others, don't remember) it can actually [introduce vulnerabilities](https://hackademix.net/2009/11/21/ies-xss-filter-creates-xss-vulnerabilities/) so you might want to check the user agent before you add the header.

Answer (score 10):

If your Web app is an ASP.Net MVC application , it is very easy to enable using the web.config file.
All you need to do is add a Custom Header as in the following config entry.

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
   </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

It is always better if you can cconfigure the IIS Response header section as well.

[image]

Comment: Corrected tagging <remove name="X-Powered-By" /> <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" /> otherwise it shows error.

Comment: In my case, I have to place it within <system.webserver> tag.